# Detect gamepad other than Xbox

Tags: uwp, hid, gamepad

I'm building an UWP app and I wan't it to be able to detect a gamepad (or joysticks and other such devices) but I'm having trouble doing this because these namespaces:

```
Windows.Gaming.Input.RawGameController.RawGameControllers
Windows.Gaming.Input.Gamepad.Gamepads
```

Are only able to detect Xbox gamepads and I have a Genius gamepad. I also see I cannot install `SlimDX` in an UWP project because they are build for `net40`.

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. You can use `Windows.Gaming.Input.RawGameController` to detect controllers other than Xbox.

Answer (score 0):

CAVE! If you are using Windows 10 on IoT, all of these APIs do not work as of Version 10.0.18299.15. Instead, you must use the HIDDevice class and parse the information by hand!

Comment: Do you suppose I can build SlimDX to target UWP?

Comment: Not sure. I used HIDDevice and it worked for me. Send me an email at tamhan aht tamoggemon bubblething come and I will send you some code; am not allowed to post it here for legal reasons.